# Stream Closed exception is thrown when 'mail.pop3.filecache.enabled' is true

Tags: java, file-io, jakarta-mail, pop3

I've written a Java-based standalone program (using JavaMail API v1.4.4) to read email messages from a POP3 server and I've also set the property `mail.pop3.filecache.enable` to *true* using:

`props.put("mail.pop3.filecache.enable", "true");`

Consistently, I'm getting the following runtime `Stream Closed` exception from `message.getContent()` method for a *particular* email message:

**Exception stracktrace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream closed
    at javax.mail.util.SharedFileInputStream.newStream(SharedFileInputStream.java:507)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.getContentStream(POP3Message.java:242)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimePartDataSource.getInputStream(MimePartDataSource.java:98)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:107)
    at javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:774)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:521)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1419)
    at ReadPop3Email.readPOP3Account(ReadPop3Email.java:290)
    at ReadPop3Email.main(ReadPop3Email.java:73)
```

Line no.290 of **ReadPop3Email.java** is the following:

`Object object = message.getContent();`

But, if I set `mail.pop3.filecache.enable` to *false*, I don't see any exception.  However, we want to make use of the property `mail.pop3.filecache.enable` to *true*,  since it will cache message data in a temporary file rather than in memory, as per JavaMail doc.

Why am I getting this exception when `filecache` is enabled?  What's going wrong? Any help/suggestion are highly appreciated. I'm using JDK1.6, if this matters.

**EDIT:**
Though I cannot share/post the original source code, I've pasted below the modified version of my original source code.

```
public class ReadPop3Email
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("mail.mime.parameters.strict", "false");
        System.setProperty("mail.mime.ignoremultipartencoding", "false");

        ReadPop3Email pop3Email = new ReadPop3Email();
        pop3Email.readPOP3Account();
    }

    public static String[] getPOP3Info()
    {
        return new String[]{"mypop3host.net", "110", "jack@example.net", "password"};
    }

    public Properties getPOP3Properties()
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.pop3.timeout", "30000");
        props.put("mail.pop3.connectiontimeout", "10000");
        props.put("mail.pop3.filecache.enable", "true");
        return props;
    }

    public void readPOP3Account()
    {
        String server = getPOP3Info()[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(getPOP3Info()[1]);
        String username = getPOP3Info()[2];
        String password = getPOP3Info()[3];
        Session session = null;
        Store store = null;
        Folder folder = null;
        POP3Folder pf = null;
        Message message = null;
        Message[] messages = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("-------------- Started processing POP3 account: " + username + " -----------------");
            session = Session.getInstance(getPOP3Properties());

            System.out.println("Getting the session for accessing email.");
            store = session.getStore("pop3");

            store.connect(server, port, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connection established with POP3 server.");

            folder = store.getDefaultFolder();

            folder = folder.getFolder("inbox");
            System.out.println("Getting the Inbox folder.");

            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            pf = (POP3Folder) folder;
            System.out.println("Total messages found: " + folder.getMessageCount());

            messages = folder.getMessages();

            //Message no. 26 is the one having this issue
            message = messages[26 - 1];

            System.out.println("Message number: " + message.getMessageNumber());
            System.out.println("Message UID: " + pf.getUID(message));
            System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0].toString());
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("Received date: " + message.getReceivedDate());
            System.out.println("Sent date: " + message.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("Content Type: " + message.getContentType());
            System.out.println("Disposition: " + message.getDisposition());
            boolean isMultipart = (message.getContent() instanceof Multipart);
            System.out.println("Message is multipart? " + isMultipart);

            if (!isMultipart) {
                getBodyContent(message);
            }

            folder.close(true);
            store.close();

            System.out.println("-------------- Completed processing POP3 account: " + username + " -----------------");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void getBodyContent(Message message)
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("============== BODY CONTENT STARTS HERE ==============");
            Object object = message.getContent();
            if (object instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("STRING content follows below: \n" + (String) object);
            } else if (object instanceof InputStream) {
                System.out.println("INPUTSTREAM content");
                InputStream is = (InputStream) object;
                int c;
                while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.write(c);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("============== BODY CONTENT ENDS HERE ==============");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more that only line nr. 290? E.g. at least ~20 lines so we see what are you doing there... (you can share whole method... no problem at all!)

Comment: @OndrejKvasnovsky: Pasted above slightly modified version of my original source code.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that the file cache is removed when the folder is closed or the JVM terminates.

Comment: Though I cannot share/post the original source code, I've pasted above slightly modified version of my original source code.

Comment: But I don't think, in this case, that's not the issue.